# I want to display the message "no result found" when the query returns no result

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am using the following code to search in the site..I wish to display the message "no result found" when the query returns no result.What changings should i do in the code

The HTML is:

```
<div class="form-container">
     <form method="get" action="search.php">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search keywords..."/>
      <input type="submit" name="find" value="">
     </form>
    </div>
```

The PHP is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['find'])){
 $search = @$_GET['search'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `me` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%$search%'";
 $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)):
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_category = $row['post_category'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,700);
    $post_video = $row['post_video'];
    $post_misc = $row['post_misc'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
?>


   <a class="post_title" href="complete_post.php?complete1=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
   <?php echo $post_title; ?>
   </a>
   <p style="color:#949494; font-family:calibri; text-align:justify; margin-left:8px; width:700px; font-size:15pt; float:left;">
   <span style="float:left; font-size:9pt; font-family:arial; color:#959595;">
   By <b><?php echo $post_author; ?></b> on <b><?php echo $post_date; ?></b> in 
   <b><?php echo $post_category; ?></b>
   </span>
   </br>
    <?php echo $post_content; ?>...
   </p>
   <a href="complete_post.php?complete=<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="r-m">
   Read more..
   </a>
<?php endwhile; } ?>
```

Comment: it all comes down to "if".

Comment: simple, old plain donditions, if() {}

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if`-condition before your `while`-loop

```
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if ( ! empty($run) && (! empty($_GET['search'])) ) {
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)):
    // your while code
  endwhile;
} else {
  echo "Nothing Found";
}
```

Comment: I tried but this returns all the posts when the empty value is searched

Comment: Your question mentions empty query result, you now seem to talk about empty search term. Which one do you want to trigger?

Comment: When the search field is empty and i click on the submit button,the page displays all the posts..

Comment: You are mixing two things. There is the situation in which the search field is empty, which means the `LIKE` part of your query is not used and every post will meet the requirements of the query so every post is displayed. The thing you seemed to ask about was "if the query returns no result" this happens when the actual query doesn't find any posts that meat the requirements. No results found and No search term entered are not the same thing. I'll adjust my code

Comment: Thank you! @RST..!

Answer (score 0):

The num_rows function will return the number of rows fetched by the query.  This should do it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['find'])){
 $search = @$_GET['search'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `me` WHERE `post_title` LIKE '%$search%'";
 $run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($run->num_rows != 0){
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)):
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $post_category = $row['post_category'];
    $post_author = $row['post_author'];
    $post_title = $row['post_title'];
    $post_content = substr($row['post_content'],0,700);
    $post_video = $row['post_video'];
    $post_misc = $row['post_misc'];
    $post_image = $row['post_image'];
    $post_date = $row['post_date'];
?>


   <a class="post_title" href="complete_post.php?complete1=<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
   <?php echo $post_title; ?>
   </a>
   <p style="color:#949494; font-family:calibri; text-align:justify; margin-left:8px; width:700px; font-size:15pt; float:left;">
   <span style="float:left; font-size:9pt; font-family:arial; color:#959595;">
   By <b><?php echo $post_author; ?></b> on <b><?php echo $post_date; ?></b> in 
   <b><?php echo $post_category; ?></b>
   </span>
   </br>
    <?php echo $post_content; ?>...
   </p>
   <a href="complete_post.php?complete=<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="r-m">
   Read more..
   </a>
<?php endwhile; 
} else { ?>
<p>There are no results to display.</p>
<?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: I am unable to understand the last 4 lines of your code @ShoeLace1291 .